# Setting DataReader = nothing

Tags: .net, datareader

In my project I have seen that at many places developer has just nullify the DataReader object after use and hasn't close or dispose..
I want to know the advace effect of doing so, I mean nullifying the datareader and not closeing them.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is to encapsulate the code which uses the DataReader in a using block.

Comment: Dear Gerrie, Using / With block will not solve the problem because developer has already put nothing/ null at proper places, but haven't used .close() or .dispose() method in entire function.